# Can one make a scalable vector background in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, gradient

I'd like to make a linear background gradient that I can scale using the same tools I would for a vector shape (ie. transform).  Is this possible?  How?

Note, if I create a layer style gradient it spans the entire canvas which I do not want, further in order to edit it I need to adjust the stop points in the gradient editor which is imprecise as it's based on percentages. I want a vector gradient that only spans half the canvas and which I can resize or snap to a guideline without pixelating/banding the way a raster gradient would when streched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the gradient in a separate, oversized document, then place that as a Smart Object. Or just make your gradient full-canvas as a layer and turn that into a Smart Object. Either way, you end up with something you can scale easily.

To adjust the gradient stops with visual feedback, double-click the SO layer icon to open it in a separate window, then choose Window > Arrange > Tile to see the gradient document and your working document side by side. Your working document updates every time you save the PSB.